# how to get the value after the second instance of a character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have these strings:

XXXXX - XXXX - XXX - XXXX 
XXXX - XXX - XXXXXXX

I need to grab the value AFTER the second instance of '-'

so in the scenario above, I would get:

XXX - XXXX 
XXXXXXX

how do I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` are your friends here.
Try this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'XXXXX - XXXX - XXX - XXXX'

SELECT SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING( @str, CHARINDEX( '-', @str ) + 1, LEN( @str ) ), CHARINDEX( '-', @str ) + 1, LEN( @str ) )
```

Returns `XXX - XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

This is a XML/XQuery based solution:

```
SELECT *, y.ColB.query('root/i[position() gt 2]').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS SomethingVeryImportant
FROM ( 
    SELECT 'XXXXX - XXXX - XXX - XXXX'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'XXXX - XXX - XXXXXXX'
) AS x(ColA)
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'<root><i>' + REPLACE(x.ColA, N'-', N'-</i><i>') + N'</i></root>') ) AS y(ColB)
```

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d12f6cef765c0c2e8269632f31b7b964)**